# Maven-failsafe-plugin: skipTests configuration does not work for Spring Boot 1.4 integration tests

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I want to use a Spring Boot test integration capabilities with maven. When I run the next command I see that it is not working as I expected:

```
mvn clean install -DskipIntegrationTests=true
```

it is started to run integration tests but should skip them.
My questions are:

1. how can I control integration tests execution with maven ?
2. Does I really need a maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Note: I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE
My POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>${skipIntegrationTests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

My integration tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("development")
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:beforeTestRun.sql"),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:afterTestRun.sql")
})
public class AdminTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void get_all_admins() {
       //TODO: code here
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you identifying that test as an `integration test` compared to a normal unit test?

Comment: I do not identify, probably I missed some maven plugin configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to have a look at how the failsafe plugin works. Specifically how it identifies tests that should be part of the integration test phase:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> `**/IT*.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "IT".
>   `**/*IT.java` - includes all of its
>   subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "IT".
>   `**/*ITCase.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "ITCase".
>
> If the test classes do not follow
>   any of these naming conventions, then configure Failsafe Plugin and
>   specify the tests you want to include.